# Do a post since a JQUERY dialog?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got two buttons inside of `HtmlForm` and it was working so well, to differenciate of I pass the name of the button in the actionName. Look below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string button, QuizCompletedViewModel q)
    { // QuizCompletedViewModel is the model of my razor view
         ...            
    }


@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Quiz", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))
{
<div>
    <!-- Old code using two buttons for post  -->
    <div class="float-right">
@*        <input name="button" type="submit" value="save" />
        <input name="button" type="submit" value="done" />*@
        <input name="button" type="button" value="done" />
    </div>

    <div id="dialog-form">
        <input name="button" type="button" value="Cancel" />
        <input name="button" type="submit" value="Save" />
        <input name="button" type="submit" value="Done" />
    </div>
</div>


<div id="question-container">
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++) {
    ...
}
</div>
}
```

Then I need to change the two buttons of my current view and show a pop with these two buttons as is above (`id="dialog-form"`). By this momment is a little difficult to me using JQuery when the user press buttons and perform a POST like the old code.

Can you lend me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be a help to you, you will have to tweak it for your needs, Jquery Dialog displays a Continue button in my code example and you bind a function to it, you can replace the Asp.net Webforms __doPostBack with something that will cause a postback on your MVC page.

```
 $("#dialog").dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        height: 380,
                        width: 650,
                        modal: true,
                        close: function () {
                            $('#btnCreateAccount').button('refresh');
                        },
                        buttons: {
                            'Continue': function () {
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                                __doPostBack($("#<%=btnCreateAccount.ClientID %>").attr("name"), '');
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Yes, I based your example.. __doPostBack does not work for me. Also I used $.post but either work. So I used submit methods but adding some extra data like `<input name=""></input>`